# Importing XML Table of results from a query URL

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have several web pages on our work Intranet that are used for basic queries. We query by product ID and the results are displayed on the page as a table, dynamically adjusted to the size of the results.

If I try to import the query directly I do get a response. I am importing by using:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://picture-us.MASKED.com/imaging_orders/list_data?utf8=%E2%9C%93&work_order_enum=LEGACY_WORK_ORDER&tab=1&asin=MASKED&warehouse=SDF8&commit_asin=Search&utf8=%E2%9C%93&work_order_enum=LEGACY_WORK_ORDER&tab=1&asin=MASKED&warehouse=SDF8&commit_asin=Search" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

My results are the following all in one cell (MASKED to hide confidential data):

```
<tr>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedOrders[]" id="selectedOrders_"   value="10040859069" />
    </td>
    <td>2019-06-25 14:06:53</td>
    <td>MASKED</td>
    <td>MASKED</td>    
    <td>COMPLETE</td>
    <td><button onclick="toggleEvents(this)" class="toggleEventButton" type="button">Show</button><br />
    <div style="display:none;" id="10040859069" class="imagingOrderEvents">
    <table>
      <thead> 
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>New Status</th>
          <th>User Id</th>
          <th>Module</th>
          <th>Change Reason</th>
         </tr>
       </thead> 
       <tbody> 
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>10040859069</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedOrders[]" id="selectedOrders_" value="10043881826" />
    </td>
    <td>2019-08-20 16:36:09</td>
    <td>MASKED</td>
    <td>MASKED</td>    
    <td>COMPLETE</td>
    <td><button onclick="toggleEvents(this)" class="toggleEventButton"   type="button">Show</button><br />
    <div style="display:none;" id="10043881826" class="imagingOrderEvents">
    <table>
      <thead> 
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>New Status</th>
          <th>User Id</th>
          <th>Module</th>
          <th>Change Reason</th>
         </tr>
       </thead> 
       <tbody> 
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>10043881826</td>
    </tr>
```

Ideally I would like to be able to import the table data into individual cells. I don't actually need them to have any header information, as I only need to extract the data results and utilize that piece of information in other code.

Edit added page source info from url:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
<status>
    <code>OK</code>
    <description>OK</description>
</status>
<table_body>
<![CDATA[
  <tr>
  <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedOrders[]" id="selectedOrders_" value="10044295826" />
  </td>
  <td>2019-08-27 07:08:18</td>
  <td>ZZUL4SMRCB</td>
  <td>MASKED_PHOTO1</td>    
  <td>READY</td>
  <td><button onclick="toggleEvents(this)" class="toggleEventButton" type="button">Show</button><br />
  <div style="display:none;" id="10044295826" class="imagingOrderEvents">
  <table>
    <thead> 
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>New Status</th>
        <th>User Id</th>
        <th>Module</th>
        <th>Change Reason</th>
       </tr>
     </thead> 
     <tbody> 
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </td>
  <td>10044295826</td>
</tr>
]]>
</table_body>
<last_page />
</root>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the entire XML response.

Comment: That is the entire response as far as I am able to determine. As I stated above the normal usage is a internal page the product ID's are submitted and the table is generated on that page based on the results of the query. If I run the query standalone in a browser the page source above is what is produced. If the query is run through excel the same data with the source tags is what is produced in a single cell.